# WooCommerce Products Not Showing Up On Front-End After WP All Import

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, product

I setup a fresh WooCommerce install, imported my products from a .csv using WP All Import. The products seemed to import fine. They show up in the back-end. I can search for them in the back-end. I can even go to a single product page and see the product data. But if I try to query them on the front end, or go to a category page, no products get returned.

Unless I manually update a product. I don't even have to change any data, just open the product in the admin, hit the update button, and suddenly now it's showing up in queries.

I've run through all the suggestions in this other post: [WooCommerce product not showing up in search after deletion and reupload using WP All Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70868330/woocommerce-product-not-showing-up-in-search-after-deletion-and-reupload-using-w)

Any idea why a manual update would make the products suddenly visible in queries? I don't want to manually update 5000 products. Also new products will be imported in the future, and I don't want to run into this issue with those products too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check if it's related to product visibility? There is a flag in Woocommerce products that decides product visibility. Check for that in your CSV. Also, if it's absent just add it as a column in CSV, that might help.

Comment: `wc_update_product_lookup_tables();` run this function on after import finished hook. Or try this [free woocommerce product import plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)